# Using POST Method in PHP Form but the Parameters Appear in the URL

Tags: php, html

My current page is index.php?page=21. In that page I have a form with POST method to post myParamater so that it won't appear in the URL.

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php?page=21">
      <input name="myParamater" type="hidden" value="1">
      <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

When I click my submit button, something strange happens. It brings me to index.php?myParamater=1. And also when I change my form to

```
<form method="POST" action="self">
      <input name="page" type="hidden" value="21">
      <input name="myParamater" type="hidden" value="1">
      <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

It brings me to index.php?page=21&myParamater=1

What should I do so I can redirect to my current page (index.php?page=21)  with new paramater myParameter without make myParamater appear in the URL?

Comment: You will always be able to get that `myparameter` in `$_POST`. explain me what are you trying to do?

Comment: check if any javascript operates in this form, maybe through javascript (or jquery) your get param becomes post param.

Comment: have you considered to use $.ajax of jquery to submit the form instead of the classic way ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your method post is not working and it is using GET method by default. I tried it in my browser and it works correctly.. Try using other browser.. or reload it..

Comment: Is your current page already including paramater in the url like mine index.php?page=21 ?

Comment: This should not be an answer. This is a comment on question.